# I am getting an ImportError when I try to import pytesseract. It says it is most likely due to a circular import

Tags: python, tesseract, importerror, python-tesseract

This is the very simple code I am running on my Jupyter Notebook.

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

im = Image.open("ocrtest.jpg")

text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im, lang = 'eng')
print(text)
```

I have also tried using `from pytesseract import image_to_string` but it is still resulting in the following error:

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 from PIL import Image
----> 2 import pytesseract
      3 pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = r'C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'
      4 im = Image.open("ocrtest.jpg")

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\__init__.py:1, in <module>
----> 1 from pytesseract import image_to_string

ImportError: cannot import name 'image_to_string' from partially initialized module 'pytesseract' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\__init__.py)
```

I am using Jupyter Notebook through Anaconda, and Anaconda already has pytesseract installed. But for this code I am using the separate pytesseract downloaded from the Tesseract installer for Windows: https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki
Is this error happening because the two files might be named the same? How do I go about fixing this?

Comment: You probably have a file called `image_to_string.py` in your working directory.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Where would I find this file, and what should I do to it?

Comment: Or a file named `pytesseract.py`. What should I do to it - rename it

Comment: @PranavHosangadi You're right, there was a file named <pytesseract.py>. However, even after I renamed it, the error continued to show up. The confusing part for me is before this error ever came up for the first time, the code ran correctly once. After that one time, I ran it again, and then the error began. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: If there's a `__pycache__` folder, get rid of it